# How to point Django app to new DB without dropping the previous DB?

Tags: python, django

I am working on Django app on branch A with `appdb` database in settings file. Now I need to work on another branch(B) which has some new DB changes(eg. new columns, etc). The easiest for me is to point branch B to a different DB by changing the `settings.py` and then apply the migrations. I did the migrations but I am getting error like `1146, Table 'appdb_b.django_site' doesn't exist`. So how can I use a different DB for my branchB code without dropping database `appdb`?

Comment: was **appdb_b** a copy of **appdb** before you switched to the other branch ?

Comment: `appdb_b` is an empty database. it is not a copy

Comment: that might be why you get errors. as migrations files tell the story of how the models change, when you run one of them, it is excpected that the database status is similar to how it was then. 
you may try to use a copy of **appdb** first, then write a custom migration file that would remove everything you don't need (i'm not sure it's a very clean way to do it, but let me know if it helps)

Comment: well i need a fresh copy of db. i remove all auto-generated migration files. dropping the database first then create it again and then run the migrate seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The existing migration files have information that causes the migrate command to believe that the tables should exist and so it complains about them not existing.

You need to MOVE the migration files out of the migrations directory (everything except **init**.py) and then do a makemigrations and then migrate.